# Code Analysis Warning Even though I am Following MSDN Guidelines CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Can someone please tell me why the following code sample is throwing the `CA2000`: Dispose objects before losing scope Code analysis Warning and  possible fix.

```
    public static EncapsulatingDisposableObject ReturnMyDisposableObject(){
        DisposableObject TempBuffer = null;
        try
        {
            TempBuffer = new DisposableObject();
            EncapsulatingDisposableObject SB = null;
            EncapsulatingDisposableObject TmpSB = null;
            try
            {
                TmpSB = new EncapsulatingDisposableObject(TempBuffer);
                TempBuffer = null;
                SB = TmpSB;
                TmpSB = null;
                return SB;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (TmpSB != null)
                {
                    TmpSB.Dispose();
                }
            }              

        }

        finally
        {
            if (TempBuffer != null)
            {
                TempBuffer.Dispose();
            }


        }
}
```

`CA2000` Dispose objects before losing scope    In method '`EncapsulatingDisposableObject`.`ReturnMyDisposableObject()'`, call `System.IDisposable.Dispose` on object '`TempBuffer`' before all references to it are out of scope.

Ok for anyone who might be interested the problem was with the `EncapsulatingDisposableObject` constructor which was simple doing

```
    EncapsulatingDisposableObject(DisposableObject obj)
{
   _disposableField = obj;
}
```

Which causes the compiler to complain that the parameter passed into this wasn't disposed properly.

Comment: Have you tried DisposableObject TempBuffer = null; inside the try ?

Comment: Better you can use `using` block to call `Dispose()` internally.

Comment: Actually, if you are always nulling the object outside the finally block, it will never call Dispose?

Comment: I cannot use the using block because the `TempBuffer` is assigned to a field in the `EncapsulatingDisposableObject` class.

I cannot think of any other place to assign null To TempBuffer because it cannot be null before calling the constructor of `EncapsulatingDisposableObject` .

Comment: basically `EncapsulatingDisposableObject ` has a field of type `DisposableObject` which is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @HamzaIqbal Just noticed that 2 trying to repro the issue. I think you need to handle disposing of the DisposableObject object in the Dispose method of the EncapsulatingDisposableObject obect.

Comment: the EncapsulatingDisposableObject's Dispose is calling the dispose of its _disposableObject field, so the warning occurs despite this.

Comment: Interesting I have VC 2017 Community and its not showing up in the Analysis.

Comment: I also did a stub implementation of this exact post in VS2013 just to isolate this but with code analysis turned on and rules set to All Microsoft rules I still get the warning.